# 5G modem shows no traceroutes

Tags: networking, routing, home-networking, traceroute, mobile-broadband

I have a very bad internet connection, so I had a 4G/LTE modem to access the internet. Behind it is an asus router to which all my devices are connected. But this was a bit slow recently, so I upgraded to a 5G router, Huawei 5G CPE Pro 2, at a different provider (Telekom in Germany). Then I noticed some connection issues here and there and started investigating, though my networking knowledge is very basic.

Now I noticed something weird to me. If I use traceroute to see the route to some site using the 4G modem, traceroute shows me 15 hops to the target.

> traceroute to example.com (93.184.216.34), 30 hops max, 60 byte
> packets
>
> 1  router.asus.com (192.168.2.1)  0.146 ms  0.179 ms  0.172 ms
>
> 2  192.168.1.250 (192.168.1.250)  0.646 ms  0.799 ms  0.884 ms
>
> 3  192.168.225.1 (192.168.225.1)  3.115 ms  3.578 ms  4.800 ms
>
> .  (Multiple detailed hops)  .
>
> 15  93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34)  143.814 ms  148.034 ms  146.367 ms

But if I do this with the 5G modem, I get the first two hops from here to the modem, and then only stars.

> traceroute to example.com (93.184.216.34), 30 hops max, 60 byte
> packets
>
> 1  router.asus.com (192.168.2.1)  0.127 ms  0.160 ms  0.154 ms
>
> 2  192.168.8.1 (192.168.8.1)  0.613 ms  0.608 ms  0.652 ms
>
> 3  * * *
>
> 4  * * *
>
> ... only stars
>
> 30  * * *

What could that be? Is there some networking or IP shenanigans that the provider uses? Changing the DNS entry does not change it.

Thanks.

Comment: DNS is unrelated. This is strictly about packet TTL (does that transfer over PPP?) and ICMP TTL Exceeded messages.

Comment: PPP carries IP packets, so yes it would also carry the packet TTL which is part of the IP header.

Answer (score 1):

The provider probably just blocks most UDP ports. (Traceroute on Linux sends UDP packets, starting at port 33434 and increasing for each probe.) It is *not completely unlikely* for an LTE operator to block all but a few "known" UDP ports, e.g. with the goal of banning BitTorrent.

It is also possible that the provider blocks certain ICMP messages, but that's a bit less likely. Try to run `mtr` or `traceroute --icmp` to the same destinations; if they work, UDP is the problem, if they don't, something else is. (And perhaps try them with a very large hop limit – all the way to `mtr --max-ttl 255` instead of the default 30.)

If you have root access to a server somewhere else, run a `tcpdump -n udp` on it, then run a UDP portscan from your home LTE connection (using nmap). Compare the packets that nmap sends with the ones that the server receives (paying attention to the ones that it *doesn't* receive).